# Why twitter OAUTH not redirecting me back to application in CustomWebView in Android?

Tags: android, android-webview, twitter-oauth

I am trying to open twitter integration inside a custom webview beacuse,

[I am using this example](http://dev.bostone.us/2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/#awp::2009/07/16/android-oauth-twitter-updates/)

ctx.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl)));

If I user above code, it give a problem on pressback button. After redirection and posting status. When I press back button it goes to browser not to my application. I decide to user custom webview to avoide this by handling back event.

I am using following example. But now after authuntication browser not redirecting me back to my application but give an error, that page not found.?
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally modify my CustomeWebView class method to check if the redirecting URL is start with "----" then parse tokens from URL and finish this activity and start new activity.

I am also find some good examples to use twitter in android

https://github.com/brione/Brion-Learns-OAuth

https://github.com/marakana/OAuthDemo

http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html